# Django basic project with common functionality included

Tags: django

Does someone know any basic open source Django project with follow common applications installed:

1. Native Registration with templates.
2. Open auth registration.
3. Basic templates created.
4. Twitter Bootstrap included
5. Main page with menu app.
6. Maybe some other common things.

Something that you can start with, and jump to your special functionality and design right away. 
The only project that I'm aware of is [django-skel](https://github.com/rdegges/django-skel)
But it seemed does not include all the really common things. 
`Pinax` looks like drooped support from django-1.3 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-skel is meant as sane configuration for Django projects which clears up a lot of configuration you need to do to when you start a project.

Now it looks like what you are looking for falls closer to the [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) ball park.

That being said this wont take you long to setup yourself and you wont have to deal with the legacy of something like pinax albiet it gets you started really quick. They have a bunch of reusable apps that you could string together to get your desire result.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for disturbing without proper research, but here is something I just found and it seems totally  awesome:

```
$ mkvirtualenv mysite
$ pip install Django==1.4.1
$ django-admin.py startproject --template=https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account/zipball/master mysite
$ cd mysite
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ python manage.py syncdb && python manage.py runserver
```